# Why is this categorical Python dataframe column misbehaving

Tags: python, pandas

I dont seem to understand why this column that has been categorised. A simple comparison fails.

```
import pandas as pd
dfg = pd.DataFrame(['A+', 'A', 'A-', 'B+', 'B', 'B-', 'C+', 'C', 'C-', 'D+', 'D'],
                  index=['excellent', 'excellent', 'excellent', 'good', 'good', 'good', 'ok', 'ok', 'ok', 'poor', 'poor'])
dfg.rename(columns={0: 'Grades'}, inplace=True)

dfg['Grades'] = dfg['Grades'].astype('category',
                             categories=['D', 'D+', 'C-', 'C', 'C+', 'B-', 'B', 'B+', 'A-', 'A', 'A+'],
                             ordered=True)

grades=dfg['Grades']
for x in grades:
    print x,x>'C+'
```

See my results:

```
A+ False
A False
A- False
B+ False
B False
B- False
C+ True
C False
C- True
D+ True
D True
```

[image]

Comment: How does this "fail"?  I get the expected output: "C-" and the "D" grades come up as `True`; everything else is `False`.  You failed to supply your results and expected results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works just fine... as a Series operation, that is.

```
dfg['Grades'] > 'C+'

excellent     True
excellent     True
excellent     True
good          True
good          True
good          True
ok           False
ok           False
ok           False
poor         False
poor         False
Name: Grades, dtype: bool
```

When you perform logical comparisons on the Series, the elements are treated as Categorical values with ordering.

When you iterate over them in a loop, you inadvertently treat them as strings, so logical comparisons are evaluated lexicographically.

There's a difference between "compare the strings C+ and D-", and "compare the categories C+ and D-", which is effectively what's going on here.

Comment: You beat me and have a better explanation than I.   +1

Comment: @ScottBoston Thank you :-)

Comment: Thanks @coldspeed for this explanation. "When you perform logical comparisons on the Series, the elements are treated as Categorical values with ordering". That answers my question.